# docker command run as different uid

Tags: 20.04, docker

I am reviewing one of the dockerfile and noticed this command.

RUN |1 uid=3000699 /bin/sh -c sudo chown -hR headless:root /usr/share/applications/ # buildkit

What is the |1 within the RUN command does?

Comment: That looks like output from `docker build` or similar. You have this actually in the Dockerfile? Use code formatting for the Dockerfile contents